# Working With Multiple Instances of a Consumer (HA Cluster)

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm having problems finding any information on how to scale RabbitMQ consumers, specifically, how to work with multiple instances of the same component.

Say I have two components; A and B. I have three instances of each component set up as an HA cluster. Let's say A.1 sends a message with a key which matches B. I only want one instance of B to consume this message not all 3 of them.

Can you point me to some documentation which explains how this can be done? Ideally, some information about the load balancing approach adopted would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try going through documentation? https://www.rabbitmq.com/clients.html

Answer (score 0):

Should not be a problem as RabbitMQ uses variety of asynchronous architectural patterns to decouple applications and one of them is round robin

**Round-Robin**

By default RabbitMQ immediately dispatches (or pre-assigns) each message to the next consumer in sequence when it enters the queue. It dispatches messages evenly where where on average every consumer will get the same number of messages.

A shortcoming of this approach is when messages use uneven resources. In a situation with two workers, when all odd messages are heavy and even messages are light, one worker will be constantly busy and the other will do little work.

As shown in the example below , both the consumers will get the messages in a round robin manner , so in your case if the three instances bound to the same queue then one message will go to only one of the consumers , the **KEY is that they should bind to a common queue.**
[image]